# Check if grain exists by GUID in Microsoft Orleans

Tags: orleans

How do you check if a grain exists already for a particular Id?

Considering the below will create a new player grain with the Id I pass into `GetGrain()` if it doesn't exist, I am not sure how to check if one already exists.

```
public async Task<Guid> Create(Guid playerGuid)
    {
        var player = GrainClient.GrainFactory.GetGrain<IPlayerGrain>(playerGuid);
        var gameGuid = await player.CreateGame();

        return gameGuid;
    }
```

Comment: I'm just learning Orleans. What is the context of this method - what class is it in?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The short answer is to store some state so the grain knows whether or not it has been activated previously.

Grains in Orleans are never explicitly created or destroyed: they are always available to handle requests. So, technically, the concept of whether or not a grain exists does not apply to Orleans. On the other hand, we can ask "has a grain with this id ever been *activated* before".

There are two cases you might want to check:

1. The grain has never been activated, but you're expecting that it has. Eg: I'm calling a method on `IPlayerGrain`, but the player doesn't exist.
2. The grain has been activated previously, but you're expecting that it hasn't. Eg: I'm trying to create a new game for this player, but that id has already been taken.

In the code sample below, you can see both cases:

1. The call to `IPlayerGrain.CreateGame()` will throw an exception if the player has never been created before. Ignore the fact that I'm never setting `Created`, that could be done in some `CreatePlayer(...)` method.
2. The call to `IGameGrain.TryCreateGame(player)` returns false if the game has already been created. In that case, `IPlayerGrain.CreateGame()` will continue looping until it's found a game which hasn't been created. With a `Guid` id it's unlikely that you'll ever see a collision, but I understand the desire to be cautious - just incase the stars align and consipire against you.

```cs
public interface IPlayerGrain : IGrainWithGuidKey
{
    Task<Guid> CreateGame();
}

public class PlayerState
{
    public bool Created { get; set; }
}

public class PlayerGrain : Grain<PlayerState>, IPlayerGrain
{
    public async Task<Guid> CreateGame()
    {
        if (!this.State.Created)
          throw new InvalidOperationException("Player does not exist.");

        var thisPlayer = this.AsReference<IPlayerGrain>();

        var created = false;
        var gameId = default(Guid);
        while (!created)
        {
            // Get a new, random game grain
            gameId = Guid.NewGuid();

            // Try to create a game.
            created = await this.GrainFactory.GetGrain<IGameGrain>(gameId)
                                .TryCreateGame(thisPlayer);

            // If the game was successfully created, break out and return the id.
            // Otherwise, keep looping.
        }

        return gameId;
    }
}
```

```cs
public interface IGameGrain : IGrainWithGuidKey
{
    // Returns true if game was created, false otherwise.
    Task<bool> TryCreateGame(IPlayerGrain player);
}

public class GameState
{
    public IPlayerGrain Player { get; set; }
}

public class GameGrain : Grain<GameState>, IGameGrain
{
    public async Task<bool> TryCreateGame(IPlayerGrain player)
    {
        // If this grain already has a player, return false.
        if (this.State.Player != null) return false;

        // Otherwise, set the player, write it to storage, and return true.
        this.State.Player = player;
        await this.WriteStateAsync();
        return true;
    }
}
```

The `Create` method in your question does not need to change.